# Is there any way to print japanese characters in a textEdit?

Tags: android, eclipse

I would like to write a program that prints out Japanese characters but when I try to develop the program using eclipse and the android SDK the editor will not allow me to cut and past Japanese characters into the eclipse text editor (it just displays ?).

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Put them directly into the XML file using something like Notepad? Even better, put them into a string resource and include that.

Comment: I tried cutting and pasting a kanji chracter into the stings.xml and the editor registered it as "?".

Answer (score 1):

As @Eric mentioned in his comment, you should really put the Japanese chars in a string resource and reference that one from the layout file. Even more, you should really put the Japanese strings into a a ja-jp localized strings.xml.

Btw, showing '?' instead of the actual characters might as well be just a result of the standard font your Eclipse is configured to work with. i just tried copying some Japanese chars from Wikipedia (`ウィキペディアにようこそ！` - I hope it's nothing offensive :-)) and pasting them in a TextView and it worked just fine. The Japanese text showed both in the xml view and in the graphic designer view of my layout. I did this with a brand new wizard generated app. I am using straightforward install of the latest version of the Eclipse plugin and the latest Android SDK (tools rev. 20) on OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: How would you localize the strings.xml file?  I looked at the text file encoding and it was already UTF-8.

Comment: It's not so much localizing the xml itself, as suggesting to Android that this particular xml has content intended for particular locale. This happens by putting the strings.xml into values-ja-jp instead of just values (where you usually put the locale-independent content, which most people threat as English, in particular en-us)

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, you need to set the default encoding to UTF-8 to support unicode

> Windows > Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > {Choose file
>   type} {Selected file type} > Default encoding > UTF-8" and click
>   Update.

Comment: The default encoding for *.XML files is already UTF-8, and cutting and pasting a kanji results in the dreaded "?".

Comment: I am not sure, but when I do that in my eclipse, I am able to see the japanese chars

Comment: I figured out the problem.  I was cutting and pasting from my computer over a remote terminal connection.  When I copied and pasted from eclipse's hook up with google it pasted okay.